# Exploring expression tree within scala macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I am learning scala and for an assignment I have to write a macro.
The macro should explore the *expression tree* and then build a custom `Expression`. I managed "to take a look" at the expression by adding `println(showRaw(exprTree))`. However I still wasn't able to iterate over it and build the `Expression`

I have the following two files:
**ExpressionImplicits.scala**:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

// Expression is defined elsewhere and mainly only overrides toString()
abstract class Expression
case class Var(name: String) extends Expression
case class Number(num: Double) extends Expression
case class BinOp(operator: String, left: Expression, right: Expression) extends Expression

class ExpressionImplicitsImpl(val c: Context) {

  import c.universe._

  // Task complete macro
  // Add necessary definitions here
  // This definition was added by me
  def expr(exprTree: c.Expr[AnyRef]): c.Expr[Expression] = {
    println(showRaw(exprTree)) 
    //prints
    //Expr(Function(List(ValDef(Modifiers(PARAM), TermName("x"), TypeTree().setOriginal(Select(Ident(scala), scala.Double)), EmptyTree)), Apply(Select(Apply(Select(Ident(TermName("x")), TermName("$times")), List(Literal(Constant(2)))), TermName("$plus")), List(Apply(Select(Literal(Constant(3.0)), TermName("$times")), List(Ident(TermName("x"))))))))
    //Expr(Function(List(ValDef(Modifiers(PARAM), TermName("x"), TypeTree().setOriginal(Select(Ident(scala), scala.Double)), EmptyTree), ValDef(Modifiers(PARAM), TermName("y"), TypeTree().setOriginal(Select(Ident(scala), scala.Double)), EmptyTree)), Apply(Select(Apply(Select(Ident(TermName("x")), TermName("$times")), List(Ident(TermName("y")))), TermName("$times")), List(Ident(TermName("x"))))))

  }
}

// This definition is given
object ExpressionImplicits {
  def expr(exprTree: AnyRef): Expression = macro ExpressionImplicitsImpl.expr
}
```

**ExpressionsTest.scala**:

```
object ExpressionsTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    import ExpressionImplicits._
    val e1 = expr { (x: Double) => (x * 2) + (3.0 * x) }

    println(e1) // BinOp(+,BinOp(*,Var(x),Number(2.0)),BinOp(*,Number(3.0),Var(x)))

    val e2 = expr { (x: Double, y: Double) => x * y * x }
    println(e2) // BinOp(*,BinOp(*,Var(x),Var(y)),Var(x))

    // val e3 = expr { (x: Double) => x.toInt } // Fails during compilation
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you read https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#traversing-trees?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov No haven't found this one. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. You now only need to match on expressions, which `showRaw` dumped.

Here is the full [solution](https://github.com/ygor-sk/stackoverflow/tree/master/q53640045-scala-macro-expression):

```
object ExpressionImplicits {

  def expr(expr: AnyRef): Expression = macro expr_impl

  def expr_impl(c: blackbox.Context)(expr: c.Expr[AnyRef]): c.Expr[Expression] = {
    import c.universe._

    def treeToExpression(functionBody: c.Tree): c.Expr[Expression] = {
      functionBody match {
        case Apply(Select(leftTree, operator), List(rightTree)) =>
          val operatorName = Constant(operator.toString)
          c.Expr[Expression](q"sk.ygor.stackoverflow.q53326545.macros.BinOp($operatorName, ${treeToExpression(leftTree)}, ${treeToExpression(rightTree)})")
        case Ident(TermName(varName)) =>
          c.Expr[Expression](q"sk.ygor.stackoverflow.q53326545.macros.Var($varName)")
        case Literal(Constant(num)) if num.isInstanceOf[java.lang.Number] =>
          c.Expr[Expression](q"sk.ygor.stackoverflow.q53326545.macros.Number(${num.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Number].doubleValue()})")
        case unsupported =>
          sys.error("Unsupported function body: " + unsupported);
      }
    }

    expr.tree match {
      case Function(_, body) => treeToExpression(body)
      case unsupported =>
        sys.error("Only functions are accepted. Got: " + unsupported);
    }

  }
}
```

You should try to understand, what is going on:

- We are doing tree traversal via pattern matching and recursion. Link has already been provided in a comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#traversing-trees
- First match only checks, that the top tree is a definition of a function
- We than match recursively on function body

  - `List(rightTree)` means, that we expect methods with exactly one argument, e.g. `x.foo(y)`, `x foo y`, `x.+(y)`, `x + y`, but not `x.foo()`, `x.foo(y, z)`, `x.+(y, z)`
- We build and combine parts of the output tree using Scala macro [quasiqotes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/intro.html)
- We use fully qualified names for `BinOp`, `Var` and `Number`, so that consumer of the macro does not have to import these subclasses

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive explanation. Indeed for me was traversing the tree and the pattern matching the issue. I did not "see" the proper pattern to match against. Thanks for clarifying.